# Is it possible to get the winding order in the fragment shader?

Tags: android, opengl-es, fragment-shader, glsles

I am currently working with OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android and I find it a pretty expensive solution (in my case) to store a normal vector for each vertex or even for each fragment. I would like to determine the facing direction of the triangle in the fragment shader, having only position attributes of the vertices (and UV coordinates if that would help). 
Is there a way to implement this? As far as I know OpenGL knows the winding order of the triangles and takes advantage of it when rendering, however, I didn't find any solution to receive this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a built-in variable for this. It is named `gl_FrontFacing`, and is of type `bool`.

For example, if you wanted to color the front facing triangles yellow, and the back facing triangles cyan, you would use the following in your fragment shader:

```
if (gl_FrontFacing) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
} else {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL uses the winding order to determine the facing of triangles, so that when face culling is enabled invisible faces are not rasterized at all. However, your vertex shader is run for each vertex and you don't have access to other vertices because of the parallel nature of the GPU.

Having access to the other vertices in the same primitive is possible using geometry shaders. If I'm not mistaken it's available as an extension to OpenGL ES 3.1 but not before.

Comment: I thought the fragment shader would know which vertices define it's shape, since it gets the values from the vertex shader. But what does the following sentence mean than? Doesn't this imply that the fragment shader knows the winding order?


"The Fragment Shader gets a built-in input value saying whether the fragment was generated by the triangle's front face (this will always be true for non-triangular primitives)." 
(from [link](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Face_Culling) )

Comment: Since you mentioned about storing normals being too expensive I thought you needed to calculate normals on the fly. Now that I read your question again, looks like what you need is just gl_FrontFacing.

Comment: Calculating normals would be the best solution in my case, I am thankful you mentioned geometry shaders.  But I still don't understand why the fragment does not know anything about it's position in world space. Why can't I just get 3 random vertices from the fragment shader's plane?

Comment: Well, actually you can pass a varying from the vertex shader(where you know the world coordinates of your vertices) to the fragment shader so for each fragment you know what it is in absolute coordinates. But because the GPU runs many threads in parallel, each fragment execution is independent. That's why you cannot access information about other fragments in the same primitive.